# Vue3 plugin update output when property is updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

## I'm trying to output a localized text which updates basing on the language selected.

In order to do so, I've created a plugin which contains the following function

```
app.config.globalProperties.$trans = (key) => {
    return findTranslation(key, app.config.globalProperties.$language);
}

// I have two sources of content, this function handles it
function findTranslation(key, language){
    if(key.includes('.')){
        try{
            let parts = key.split('.');
            return translations1[language][parts[0]][parts[1]];
        }
        catch(error){
            return key;
        }
    }
    else
        return _.get(translations2, key, key);
}
```

which is called from the component using `{{ this.$trans('text_to_translate') }}`. So far so good, it works flawlessly. The problem I'm facing is that it needs to update when the language is changed.

How can I make it update the output of all the translations, when I call the following function defined in the plugin?

```
app.config.globalProperties.$changeLanguage = (key) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$language = key;
}
```

**I think I should use a watcher**, but I don't know

- what to import inside the plugin
- how to re-render the outpur, since it's a simple return function

Another solution could be to return a computed property, but that doesn't sound right to me...

### It is not an option

- to reload the content entirely
- to re-render the components

Ideally, I would like to re-render only the output of `{{ this.$trans('text_to_translate') }}`

Comment: `app.config.globalProperties.$language` should be reactive data. Probably a [ref](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)

Comment: I dig into the documentation but I still have problems with the return value, since it doesn't update. I feel I should use `this.$trans('some_text').value` and use the `computed(() => findTranslation())` but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.config.globalProperties.$language` should be reactive (so when it changes, Vue knows it should re-render the component/template)

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

app.config.globalProperties.$language = ref('en')

app.config.globalProperties.$trans = (key) => {
    return findTranslation(key, app.config.globalProperties.$language.value);
}

app.config.globalProperties.$changeLanguage = (key) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$language.value = key;
}
```

Demo:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  
})

const translations = {
  en: {
    hello: "Hello!"
  },
  cz: {
    hello: "Ahoj!"
  }
}

app.config.globalProperties.$language = Vue.ref('en')

function findTranslation(key, language){
  return translations[language][key];
}

app.config.globalProperties.$trans = (key) => {
    return findTranslation(key, app.config.globalProperties.$language.value);
}

app.config.globalProperties.$changeLanguage = (key) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$language.value = key;
}

app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.2/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div>
    {{ $trans('hello') }}
  </div>
  <select v-model="$language.value">
    <option>en</option>
    <option>cz</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: for as much as I would love to implement your solution, it doesn't work... does it work for you? because I must admit it seems correct

Comment: I found the error: I was receiving the same translation for each language key... Thank you!